# Xcode 9 thinks I have two remotes on a project... I don't - how can I remove the second one?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

This is something that's been bugging me for a while... So far I've been working around it by committing and pushing via terminal, but it would be nice to get it sorted.

In Xcode, there are two remotes listed in the source control navigator of my project.
[image]

In terminal, there aren't:
[image]

Where is Xcode storing this remote so I can remove it?

I've seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363328/how-do-i-remove-a-second-remote-git-repo-from-an-xcode-project) before, but it doesn't seem to be stored in the same way in Xcode 9.

Comment: I came across same problem, did you try doing fetch and refresh status ? It worked for me.

Comment: Yup, doesn't seem to change anything for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution was to manually delete derived data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have repo on remote and only showing in XCode then you can try this so that you won't lose any data,

Where you can delete the remote it self. Not sure if it will work or not.

[image]

Comment: There is a repo there but not one that I push to from this project. I deleted it anyway but there's still the repo showing in source navigator and it says "Push to remotes" from the commit screen

Comment: If you got back up of your project then you can try pushing it to the remote, cz As you know it might delete your repo from remote too. It's upto you if you want to take a chance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855849/xcode-remove-repository-from-project

Comment: I have no xccheckout files in the xcworkspace or xcodeproj packages

Comment: You can remove your repo from pointing to any of the repo from terminal, and once it will not show you anything on the list of remote repo in XCode, you can make it point it again to your origin.